# Downloading and merging 0.5 minute WorldClim data for (long) list of coordinates using R

Tags: raster, r, code-review

I want to download temperature and precipitation data from WorldClim for a huge list of coordinates.  I am working in R, and have a solution using getData() from raster(), but it's going to take forever for the giant list of coordinates I have.  I posted a similar [question over on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556556/how-to-streamline-and-speed-up-loop-with-getdata-package-in-r) in hopes I could streamline the looping.  However, I think even if I can streamline the looping, this might take forever.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a more efficient way of doing this?

I've Googled a whole bunch, and can't find any solutions in R.  I do have a reproducible working example:

```
# Download and merge 0.5 minute MAT/MAP data from WorldClim for a list of lon/lat coordinates
# This is based on https://emilypiche.github.io/BIO381/raster.html

# Make a dataframe with coordinates
coords <- data.frame(Lon = c(-83.63, 149.12), Lat=c(10.39,-35.31))

# Load package
library(raster)

# Make an empty dataframe for dumping data into
coords3 <- data.frame(Lon=integer(), Lat=integer(), MAT_10=integer(), MAP_MM=integer())

# Get WorldClim data for all the coordinates, and dump into coords 3
for(i in seq_along(coords$Lon)) {
  r <- getData("worldclim", var="bio", res=0.5, lon=coords[i,1], lat=coords[i,2]) # Download the tile containing the lat/lon
  r <- r[[c(1,12)]] # Reduce the layers in the RasterStack to just the variables we want to look at (MAT*10 and MAP_mm)
  names(r) <- c("MAT_10", "MAP_mm") # Rename the columns to something intelligible
  points <- SpatialPoints(na.omit(coords[i,1:2]), proj4string = r@crs) #give lon,lat to SpatialPoints
  values <- extract(r,points)
  coords2 <- cbind.data.frame(coords[i,1:2],values)
  coords3 <- rbind(coords3, coords2)
}

# Convert MAT*10 from WorldClim into MAT in Celcius
coords3$MAT_C <- coords3$MAT_10/10
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556556